How do I write a query for inner join

I want to write a select query that shows me first_name, last_name and the management_name. Each employee row has a management column, which  is equal to the employee_id of the manager.
This is what I wrote, but it doesn't work well:
select 
  e.first_name , 
  e.last_name , 
  o.firstname AS management_name 
from employee e
join employee o  ON e.employee_id = o.management


i mean i wanna have the names of managers base on column management

Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?

BTW: I recognize a screenshot from PhpMyAdmin.  Does that support [tag:sql-server] too?

What is a "management witch"?

"but it doesnt work well" is a very vague description. What are you expecting?

If you intend that employee e is the subordinate and employee o is their manager, then you have the join condition reversed. The manager's employee_id should be matched up with the subordinate's management value with ON e.management = o.employee_id.
The corrected query would then be:
select 
  e.first_name , 
  e.last_name , 
  o.firstname AS management_name 
from employee e
join employee o  ON e.management = o.employee_id

Also, if you wish your results to show that employee "Chandler Bing" has no manager, you should change your inner join to a left join.
